# Add new text to label

Tags: c#

I'd like to do the following:

- insert text from a dropdownlist into the label when you press abutton
- then after a second button click, add another text at first
- after another button click, another text on the same label

How can this be done?

label1 = combobox item1 + combobox item 2 + ... item n, after clicking

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = item1 + item2, ...;

```
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "item1")
        {                               
            text = "item1";
        }            
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "item2")
        {                   
            text = "item2";
        }                     
    }
```

Comment: I didn't put that -1, but 99% of the time it is because you didnt' include any code that shows you've actually tried something first. Look at the FAQ here for asking questions.

Comment: Which label?  Is this thick client (Winforms or WPF?) or web (ASP, MVC, etc)?  You don't give enough information for someone to answer your question...

Comment: Can you please add your code? it would be helpful to see what are you trying to do

Comment: As usual: "What have you tried?"

Comment: Are you clicking the same button three times or three different buttons?

Comment: label1 = combobox item1 + combobox item 2 + ... item n, after clicking

Comment: Somebody registered domain for such questions http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: is this windows forms?

Answer (score 2):

You need three things:

1. A button click handler (assuming you are clicking a single button)
2. A class-scoped integer that counts the number of clicks
3. A series or if/else statements or a switch statement with cases that change the action based on the number of your click.

Light code sample:

```
 private int _btnClickCount = 0; // your class-scoped variable

 // your button click handler
 private void SomeButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args) {
     if (_btnClickCount == 0)
          // do something
     else if (_btnClickCount == 1)
          // do something else
     // etc.

     _btnClickCount++;
 }
```